# Alternative to Wilcoxon signed-rank test, for data where many pairs are equal

Tags: discrete-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have several discrete datasets with a small range (-2 to +2) which I want to test against the null hypothesis "the distribution is centred around zero".

The Wilcoxon signed-rank test was suggested to me as an appropriate choice, and some answers on this site back this up. The issue is that, for some datasets, a large portion of the pair deltas are 0, meaning most of the samples are discarded. The result is that some datasets pass the test at 95% confidence while others with nearly identical distributions fail it.

What would be a good alternative test for such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article:

> On Neutral Responses (Zeros) in the Sign Test and Ties in the
>   Wilcoxon–Mann–Whitney Test Ronald H Randles  The American Statistician
>   Vol. 55, Iss. 2, 2001

Would seem to apply directly to your question.

Comment: Thanks. For the record, the **majority preference** hypothesis seems the appropriate choice as suggested by the paper.