# Test for pairs of small integers

Tags: statistical-significance, permutation-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank, paired-data, mcnemar-test

I have two classifiers, say $A$ and $B$ and I am performing 10$\times$10-fold cross-validation on them and record the number of instances correctly classified from the test set. Unfortunately, the number of instances available is quite small, so I have only around 10 instances in each test set. Therefore, the number of correctly classified instances is between 0 and 10, like this:
\begin{array}{rrr}
\text{fold} & A & B\\
\hline
1 & 8 & 9\\
2 & 7 & 7\\
3 & 10 & 8\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
100 & 9 & 8
\end{array}

I would like to know whether $A$ and $B$ have significantly different performance.

Normally (no pun intended), I would use a paired (Welch's) $t$-test for this kind of thing, but the small test set size seems to violate the assumption of normality. Additionally, both $A$ and $B$ are quite good: they have around 90% accuracy on my dataset. This means there are a lot of ties, i.e. "concordant" pairs with $A = B \approx 9$.

It seems Wilcoxon's signed rank test is the staple for problems like this. However, I am concerned with the large number of ties. I have read [On Neutral Responses (Zeros) in the Sign Test and Ties in the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2685994) by Ronald H. Randles recommended in [an answer to another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70806/31032), but I don't really understand how should the parameter $\gamma$ be selected for my problem. Moreover, because Randles only gives a formulation for the rank-sum test, I would need to forget that my observations are paired.

If I were to run leave-one-out cross-validation instead of 10$\times$10-fold, all my responses would be $\{0, 1\}$. In this case, the appropriate test would be McNemars's (exact) test, which, as far as I know, is simply a permuation test. Would preparing a permuation test be appropriate for my data in $[0, 10] \cap \mathbb{Z}$? Because the set of absolute differences is quite small, I could even do an exact permuation test. But is that meaningful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem calls for using a permutation test, a pure non-parametric test that does not have any normality assumptions. Check the "Hot Wings" example in Section 16 of these notes: http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.04929, it is essentially identical to your problem. Hope this helps.